# Change UberMenu top level menu icon when submenu is active

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the UberMenu plugin for a WordPress site. The [link](https://wpmegamenu.com/) has an example menu. I have exactly the same, but the submenu does not open on hover, but on click.
How can I change the class of the icon on the first menu item (The Works) from (fa-cog) to for example (fa-bars) when the submenu is open and return it back when the submenu is closed.
I tried to bind it to the mouse click event on the menu item, but the fact is that you can close the submenu by simply clicking next to it, and then the icon does not change back to the original.
The functions (openSubmenu) and (closeSubmenu) are called there, but my JS level is too low to figure out how to attach a class change to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPD: Found this solution:

```
var menuItem = document.getElementById("menu-item-5796");
var menuIcon = document.querySelector("i.ubermenu-icon");

var mutationConfig = { 
    attributes: true, 
    attributeFilter: ['class']
};

var onMutate = function(mutationsList) {
    mutationsList.forEach(mutation => {
        if(menuItem.classList.contains('ubermenu-active')){
            menuIcon.classList.add('fa-bars');
            menuIcon.classList.remove('fa-cog');
        } else {
            menuIcon.classList.add('fa-cog');
            menuIcon.classList.remove('fa-bars');
        }
    });
};
```